# JavaScript click not working variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

today I'm having a problem with javascript and some variables, I try to make clicking on a button fill in the text field

Example: when clicking on "Youtube" this in the text field insert the url of youtube.

```
            <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-3"><?php echo $config['website-name']; ?></h1>
            <p class="lead"><?php echo $lang["slogan"]; ?></p>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <a id="twitter" class="btn btn-info" href="#"><?php echo $lang["twitter_1"]; ?></a>
                <a id="youtube" class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><?php echo $lang["youtube_1"]; ?></a>
                <a id="facebook" class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><?php echo $lang["facebook_1"]; ?></a>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <a id="vikipedi" class="btn btn-secondary" href="#"><?php echo $lang["wikipedia"]; ?></a>
                <a id="google" class="btn btn-success" href="#"><?php echo $lang["google_1"]; ?></a>
            </div>
            <p class="lead">
            <form class="form-group" action="index.php" method="post">
                <input id="url" name="url" type="url" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" placeholder="http://"
                       autofocus required/>
                <br>
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang["go"]; ?>"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <p style="font-size:11px">
                <small><?php echo $lang["agree"]; ?> <a
                            href="<?php echo $config['website-url']; ?>/?tos"><?php echo $lang["tos_2"]; ?></a>
                </small>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#twitter').click(function () {
        $('#url').val('https://twitter.com');
    });
    $('#youtube').click(function () {
        $('#url').val('https://youtube.com');
    });
    $('#facebook').click(function () {
        $('#url').val('https://facebook.com');
    });
    $('#google').click(function () {
        $('#url').val('https://google.com');
    });
    $('#vikipedi').click(function () {
        $('#url').val('https://wikipedia.org');
    });
</script>
```

Edit:

The following error appears:

> but requested an insecure script 'code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js'; This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: What's the issue? just [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/L4b2rjgL/) it and it's working fine.

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza I click and it does not work or is it the host's problem?

Comment: Did you get any error on your console?

Comment: I found the problem **but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js' This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>` (notice `https`)

Comment: Thank you very much, that has resolved it. It was the request in http and it was not in https as it corresponded.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145068/javascript-click-not-working-variable#comment87308449_50145068) in the comments area:

> I found the problem but requested an insecure script 'code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js'; This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

As stated in a few other answers about using HTTPS as the script's source *(to which they are correct, and I am not taking away from those neither),* it would be best if you were to use the following method which would resolve automatically to either HTTP or HTTPS, given which URL protocol is used under a given environment.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

while omitting the `http:` protocol altogether. This method is especially useful for other methods such as images, CSS, URL's, FTP, or anything that is to be used / pulled from an external protocol.

**Please note** that you won't be able to use the above method when accessing files from your own computer as `file:///`; this method is only meant for an external resource. Well you can, but the script just won't load.

Comment: Thanks @cale_b I thought I'd submit that as being complimentary to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Element with id **must be only one** on page. I think you have more when one element with id #twitter. And include all you js code at bottom of the page.

Comment: You are right but you can fix it only with the access of the jquery. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTPS and `$(document).ready(function(){})` your code will work.

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-3"><?php echo $config['website-name']; ?></h1>
            <p class="lead"><?php echo $lang["slogan"]; ?></p>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <a id="twitter" class="btn btn-info" href="#"><?php echo $lang["twitter_1"]; ?></a>
                <a id="youtube" class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><?php echo $lang["youtube_1"]; ?></a>
                <a id="facebook" class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><?php echo $lang["facebook_1"]; ?></a>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <a id="vikipedi" class="btn btn-secondary" href="#"><?php echo $lang["wikipedia"]; ?></a>
                <a id="google" class="btn btn-success" href="#"><?php echo $lang["google_1"]; ?></a>
            </div>
            <p class="lead">
            <form class="form-group" action="index.php" method="post">
                <input id="url" name="url" type="url" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" placeholder="http://"
                       autofocus required/>
                <br>
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang["go"]; ?>"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <p style="font-size:11px">
                <small><?php echo $lang["agree"]; ?> <a
                            href="<?php echo $config['website-url']; ?>/?tos"><?php echo $lang["tos_2"]; ?></a>
                </small>
            </p>
        </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#twitter').click(function() {
      $('#url').val('https://twitter.com');
    });
    $('#youtube').click(function() {
      $('#url').val('https://youtube.com');
    });
    $('#facebook').click(function() {
      $('#url').val('https://facebook.com');
    });
    $('#google').click(function() {
      $('#url').val('https://google.com');
    });
    $('#vikipedi').click(function() {
      $('#url').val('https://wikipedia.org');
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that has resolved it. It was the request in http and it was not in https as it corresponded.